# Why doesn't `debug_assert` print anything when the first argument is true?

Tags: rust

When I run this code and provide no input when asked for `lname`, then the `if` condition evaluates to true and executes the line `println!("lname is empty");` but why doesn't the `debug_assert` print anything?

```
use std::io;

struct Test {
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
}

fn main() {
    println!("Enter your point!");

    println!("Please input fname: ");

    let mut p = Test { fname: String::new(), lname: String::new() };    

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut p.fname).expect("something went wrong!");

    println!("Please input lname: ");

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut p.lname).expect("something went wrong!");

    let p = Test { fname: p.fname.trim().to_string(), lname: p.lname.trim().to_string() };

    if p.lname == "" {
        println!("lname is empty");
    }

    if p.fname == "" {
        println!("fname is empty");
    }

    debug_assert!(p.lname == "", "Last name is empty");

    println!("Full name: {} {}", p.fname, p.lname);
}
```

Additionally, is shadowing the previous variable `p` to remove the line line breaks at the end a good way to do this?

Comment: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829)

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what it's supposed to do? From the [documentation of `debug_assert!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.debug_assert!.html)

> Ensure that a boolean expression is true at runtime.
>
> This will invoke the panic! macro if the provided expression cannot be evaluated to true at runtime.

And you said

> the `if` condition evaluates to `true`

Because the condition is true, and the assertion ensures that it is true, then the assertion doesn't fail.